# Integrate Apache Drill with Apache Superset

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, sql, configure

I installed Apache Drill through the link in the [Drill Documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-the-web-ui/). Apache Drill works fine. I also installed and got Apache Superset running using docker. Superset also works totally fine.

But my goal is to integrate Superset and Drill together. The only tutorial I was able to find was a [tutorial from Dataist](http://thedataist.com/visualize-anything-with-superset-and-drill/). When following this tutorial they ask us to add a database.

Since I am running both Drill and Superset in my local machine they ask us to type `drill+sadrill://localhost:8047/dfs/test?use_ssl=False` as the SQLAlchemy URI.  They ask us to test the connection by pressing test connection.

When pressing test connection I get an error message as follows.

```
ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!

The error message returned was:
Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:drill.sadrill", "stacktrace": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/home/superset/superset/views/core.py\", line 1755, in testconn
    engine = database.get_sqla_engine(user_name=username)
  File \"/home/superset/superset/utils/core.py\", line 132, in __call__
    value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/home/superset/superset/models/core.py\", line 911, in get_sqla_engine
    return create_engine(url, **params)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py\", line 435, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py\", line 61, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py\", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py\", line 240, in load
    \"Can't load plugin: %s:%s\" % (self.group, name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:drill.sadrill
"}
```

Can someone figure out why I am getting this error? Also if there are any other tutorials to follow which give a better idea on how to set up Drill and superset.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to install the SQLAlchemy Dialect for Drill:

```
git clone https://github.com/JohnOmernik/sqlalchemy-drill
cd sqlalchemy-drill
python3 setup.py install
```

(see https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#apache-drill)